# jQuery Datepicker Format for Uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2,4})/);
var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
if (match == null)
 return false;

var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var year = match[3];
var month = match[2];
var day = match[1];

var date = new Date(year, months.indexOf(month), day); // because months starts from 0.
var isOk = (date.getYear() == year && date.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && date.getDate() == day);

return isOk;
```

The above script allows user to input date in `27-Nov-14` format but not in `27-NOV-14`.

How can I change my regex to allow user to input `month` in uppercase as well, i.e. `NOV` and `Nov`.

Comment: `/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2,4})/i`

Comment: Are `nOv` or `nov` or `NoV` allowed?

Comment: We can work for `Nov` and `NOV`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `i` case insensitive flag in-order to make letters in the regex to match both upper and lower case letters.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\\d{2,4})", "i");
```

Use anchors if necessary.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\\d{2,4})$", "i");
```

Comment: `s/modifier/flag/` :) Its called flags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean.

Comment: My first code block is sed (regexp on unix). I'm just saying that stuff like `i`, `m`, `g` etc. is not called modifiers but flags: `You need to add i case insensitive modifier.` -> `You need to add i case insensitive flag.`

Comment: @null: "flags" or "modifiers" are different terms to refer to the same concept.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, unfortunately your regex ain't working.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170561/jquery-datepicker-format-for-uppaercase/27170638#comment42831993_27170561) ?

Comment: Yes, pls try it here once - http://regex101.com/. The pattern does not match the subject string

Comment: Its the same regex that I have used.

Comment: but it isn't have any `i` modifier. OR replace the regex line with `var pattern = /([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2,4})/i;`